# addinfourl instance has no attribute 'find' (python2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to find two strings in a static page for a little project. 
Using Python 2.7 and cannot upgrade (it's a given public runner I have to use).
I've written this code:

```
import urllib
url = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/context_menu"
webtxt = urllib.urlopen(url)
print webtxt.read()

str1 = "Right-click in the box below"
str2 = "Alibaba"

isRightClickText = webtxt.find(str1)
IsAlibaba = webtxt.find(str2)

def testRightClick():
    assert isRightClickText > -1

def testIsAlibaba():
    assert IsAlibaba > -1
```

This test is supposed to Pass for the first string, and Fail for the second string.

Running this code in Gitlab CI\CD constantly returns:

E   AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'find'

I've reviewed similar posts related to attributes issue but non seemed to be relevant.

Any help is welcome! (I'm new with Python)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says `addinfourl` instance has no attribute find. Please try to understand the type of `webtext`.

```
print type(webtext) #Gives the type of webtext as <type 'instance'>
```

So, all you need is to convert the `webtext` into `string` datatype in order to use `find()` method.

Change this line `webtxt = urllib.urlopen(url)` into `webtxt = str(urllib.urlopen(url))`

So, Finally code will be like:

```
import urllib
url = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/context_menu"
webtxt = str(urllib.urlopen(url))
print webtxt.read()

str1 = "Right-click in the box below"
str2 = "Alibaba"

isRightClickText = webtxt.find(str1)
IsAlibaba = webtxt.find(str2)

def testRightClick():
    assert isRightClickText > -1

def testIsAlibaba():
    assert IsAlibaba > -1
```